# Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection "Not Responding" but cannot be killed

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I launched a Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) to a remote server. The screen suddenly got frozen while connecting; the title bar indicates (`Not Responding`).

I opened another window of RDC and it worked.

My problem is that I cannot close the first window that got frozen. I have Windows 10. I tried

- Close the Window. It shows a window with "*The application is not responding... Do you want to end this process?*". Clicking on button `End Process` does not do much
- Task Manager > End Task
- Task Manager > Details > mstsc.exe > end Task

No matter what I tried, the frozen window is still here.

Any suggestion except a Logout or a reboot?

Comment: Try opening a command prompt as Administrator and enter this command: `taskkill /im mstsc.exe /f`  - if that doesn't do it, you'll probably just need to reboot.

Comment: @n8te Thanks for the comment. Didn't work either `ERROR: The process "mstsc.exe" with PID 16176 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.` Guess I will wait for next reboot.